# AssertionError in matplotlib's tight_layout()

Tags: python, matplotlib, runtime-error

I want to use matplotlib's tight_layout function on a figure with only one plot in it, but it is giving me an AssertionError. This is my code: (Note: updated w.r.t. original post)

```
def plot_histogram_00():    
    fig, _ = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))        
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.close()
```

When I run this in Eclipse on my Windows 7 computer (Python 2.7, matplotlib 1.4), it runs fine, and I get a nice output. However, when I run exactly the same code (run from a Dropbox folder) on my Mac computer (also Python 2.7, matplotlib 1.4), I receive the following Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/Dropbox/Sandbox/Histogram.py", line 139, in <module>
    plot_histogram_00();
  File "/Users/david/Dropbox/Sandbox/Histogram.py", line 38, in plot_histogram_00
    fig.tight_layout()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1654, in tight_layout
    rect=rect)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 352, in get_tight_layout_figure
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 131, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
    fig.transFigure.inverted())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1057, in __init__
    assert isinstance(transform, Transform)
AssertionError
```

Is someone able to point me in a direction where I shall start looking for the cause of this error?

UPDATE: My original code was this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_histogram_00():
    xlabels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
               'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    np.random.seed(1)
    values_A = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(xlabels)), 
                                size=200, replace=True).tolist()
    values_B = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(xlabels)), 
                                size=200, replace=True).tolist()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))
    _, bins, patches = plt.hist([values_A, values_B], normed=1,
                                bins=len(xlabels),
                                color=['#3782CC', '#AFD5FA'],
                                label=['A', 'B'])

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('my_plot_00.png')
```

Comment: Are all of these lines needed to trigger the error?

Comment: odd....  Also make sure to clean up your figures (pyplot keeps a global list, `fig.close()` after the save should be enough)

Comment: Indeed not all lines are needed, the plot itself for instance is not. I updated the original post, including the `fig.close()` statement. I still observe this behavior (working in Windows, not working in Mac).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error with python 2.7.8, matplotlib 1.4.0, on my mac. Maybe you need to reinstall matplotlib on the mac?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for mac using a matplotlib install managed by [brew-python](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python). Fixed it by completely removing it in brew (`brew uninstall --force matplotlib`) and then remove the remaining source folders in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Reinstall from pip: `pip install matplotlib`.

Main reason I used [brew-python](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python) before was an issue with matplotlib not having a standard setup.py script. As this seems fixed in the latest installation of matplotlib I suppose I can completely rely on pip now.